# Using different types of barrier lines in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, barriers

I'm trying to load line barriers into network dataset. The shapefile I prepared to use as barrier has a column called "TTtype" with two different types of "Restriction" and "Scaled Cost" and also a column called "TTFactor" with the factor for scaled cost type. When I load locations, the results are only the default values. I expected to see the number of restriction and scaled cost under the Line Barriers in network analyst panel.

What's the wrong with my approach?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, we should define Double field containing (0) for restriction and (1) for Scaled Cost instead of string field asked above.